# How can i remove the '\' from the Json

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to remove "\" from the  JSON below:

I have tried replace,replaceall functions but didn't work.

```
.replaceall('\n','');
.replace('\'', '');
.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Input:

```
"[{\"stage\":\"10 - Application\",\"oppId\":\"006234324JymAAE\",\"message\":\"Opportunity status created.\"},{\"stage\":null,\"oppId\":\"00653434427nhCBAAY\",\"message\":\"Opportunity not found or permission denied.\"}]"
```

Output :(a Valid JSON)

```
"[{"stage":"10 - Application","oppId":"006220000034JymAAE","message":"Opportunity status created."},{"stage":null,"oppId":"00654000007nhCBAAY","message":"Opportunity not found or permission denied."}]"
```

I am looking for a generic function that can remove the "\" and Spaces if any.

Code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/oppQuery/*') 
global class oppStage 
{
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(list<String> opportunityIds)
    {
        list<oppResult> results = new list<oppResult>();
        map<Id, Opportunity> oppsById = new map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT Id, StageName,  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id in: opportunityIds]);
        for(String s : opportunityIds)
        {
            Opportunity o = oppsById.get(s);
            if(o == NULL || o.StageName != 'Won')
            {
                oppResult result = new oppResult(s, NULL, 'Opportunity not found or permission denied.');
                results.add(result);
            }
        }
        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(results); //convert the List of results in to Json
        return decodedJson; 
    }

}


public class oppResult
    {
        public String oppId{get; set;}
        public String stage{get; set;}
        public String message{get; set;}


        public FResult(Id pOppId, String pStage, String pMessage)
        {
            oppId = pOppId;
            stage = pStage;
            message = pMessage;
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried using the [JSON Parser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm)?

Comment: I cannot use the JSON Parser in here. This is a post call (REST)where I am trying to query the records with a given opportunity ID List and send the records in the form of JSON by serializing the List of records .while i am sending I am having the issue with '\' .  I would like to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've "double-encoded" your JSON. To get back to "normal" JSON, just deserialize it.

---

```
// Note: \\ becomes \ when the compiler converts this to a string
String source = '"[{\\"stage\\":\\"10 - Application\\",\\"oppId\\":\\"006234324JymAAE\\",\\"message\\":\\"Opportunity status created.\\"},{\\"stage\\":null,\\"oppId\\":\\"00653434427nhCBAAY\\",\\"message\\":\\"Opportunity not found or permission denied.\\"}]"';
String decodedJson = (String)JSON.deserialize(source, String.class);
```

## Output

> [{"stage":"10 - Application","oppId":"006234324JymAAE","message":"Opportunity status created."},{"stage":null,"oppId":"00653434427nhCBAAY","message":"Opportunity not found or permission denied."}]

---

It may be that you should *not* be encoding the data into a JSON to begin with, since it already *is*.

---

Based on edit:

Apex automatically serializes the result for you. This is what's causing the double-encoding. To fix this, change this code:

```
global static list<oppResult> doPost(list<String> opportunityIds)
    // ... //
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Input Sfdxfox,                                                            
         list<StringHelper> results = new list<String>();     //Converting the list of records which are obtained by SOQL Query.                                                                        
        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(results); // passing the List to get the records in Json format 
        String decodedJson = (String)JSON.deserialize(results, String.class);
        return decodedJson;  .. I have the issue in the o/p as now "[" it is giving this response

Comment: @Donald You should not be serializing *or* deserializing, as far as I can tell. Your problems start with `String JSONString = JSON.serialize(results);`, which I suspect is *already* a JSON string. We'd have to see more code to get the full picture, though.

Comment: Please see the edited post sfdcfox...Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @Donald The problem is in your method. Edited to show the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally have this string as input:

```
"[{\"stage\":\"10 - Application\",\"oppId\":\"006234324JymAAE\",\"message\":\"Opportunity status created.\"},{\"stage\":null,\"oppId\":\"00653434427nhCBAAY\",\"message\":\"Opportunity not found or permission denied.\"}]"
```

Then valid (useful) JSON would look like this: (no surrounding double quotes)

```
[{"stage":"10 - Application","oppId":"006234324JymAAE","message":"Opportunity status created."},{"stage":null,"oppId":"00653434427nhCBAAY","message":"Opportunity not found or permission denied."}]
```

and to go from input to result would be:

```
String s = '"[{\"stage\":\"10 - Application\",\"oppId\":\"006234324JymAAE\",\"message\":\"Opportunity status created.\"},{\"stage\":null,\"oppId\":\"00653434427nhCBAAY\",\"message\":\"Opportunity not found or permission denied.\"}]"';

String t = s.replace('\\\\','').substringAfter('"').substringBeforeLAst('"');
system.debug(t);

USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|[{"stage":"10 - Application","oppId":"006234324JymAAE","message":"Opportunity status created."},{"stage":null,"oppId":"00653434427nhCBAAY","message":"Opportunity not found or permission denied."}]
```

or more succinctly and reliable (avoiding dealing with embedded `\` as legit characters in the json property values):

```
String s = '"[{\"stage\":\"10 - Application\",\"oppId\":\"006234324JymAAE\",\"message\":\"Opportunity status created.\"},{\"stage\":null,\"oppId\":\"00653434427nhCBAAY\",\"message\":\"Opportunity not found or permission denied.\"}]"';    
String t = (String) Json.deserialize(s.substringAfter('"').substringBeforeLast('"'),String.class);
System.debug(t);

USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|[{"stage":"10 - Application","oppId":"006234324JymAAE","message":"Opportunity status created."},{"stage":null,"oppId":"00653434427nhCBAAY","message":"Opportunity not found or permission denied."}]
```